# Make windows service run as if it was run from a specific user

Tags: c#, windows-services

I want to create a windows service to mount and dismount a [True Crypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) volume.

(this question is not about true crypt so if you do not know what that program that is ok. True Crypt is just a program that enables you to encrypt data. When you decrypt it then trueCrypt will create a virtual drive where you can see the contents unencrypted).

Here is the code I use in my console application:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        Test();
}

static void Test()
{
    try
    {
        // location where true crypt is installed
        const string trueCryptExeLocation = @"C:\Program Files\TrueCrypt\TrueCrypt.exe";

        // command line arguments to mount a volume located at 'C:\TC Volumes\vol1.tc' where 
        // it's password is 'demo' and it will be mounted on drive letter y
        const string mountVolumeCmd = @"/v ""C:\TC Volumes\vol1.tc"" /ly /q /p demo /f /a";

        // mount the volume on drive letter y
        Process.Start(trueCryptExeLocation, mountVolumeCmd).WaitForExit();

        // write to the volume!
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText("y:\\someFile.txt", "it works");

        // wait 30 seconds before dismounting
        Thread.Sleep(3000);

        // dismount the volume
        Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files\TrueCrypt\TrueCrypt.exe", @"/ly /q /d /f");
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
        // if there is an error write it to disk
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"A:\Dropbox\Eduardo\WindowsNodeService\WindowsNodeService\bin\Debug\startup.txt", ex.ToString());
     }
}
```

That code basically mounts a volume writes to it and dismounts it.  IF I run that program this is what I see:

[image]

1. When I open the program trueCrypt.exe I can see that the volume is actually mounted.
2. I can see that the program actually wrote to the file someFile.txt
3. The path `Y:\` exist. In other words I can open My Computer and see drive Y.

### Now my question is why if I run the same code on a windows service it runs differently but it runns ok with no errors.

In other words having the following windows service:

```
public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
{
    public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        Test(); // same method as console application
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
    }

   // etc... Test method implementation
```

Running that code runs fine. It writes to the file someFile.txt! which is great. The problem is that if I open trueCrypt I do not see the volume mounted in there. Also if I go to My Computer I do not see the drive Y. **How can I make my windows service behave like the console application?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using .Net 4.5, you can use [this Process.Start call](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed04yy3t.aspx):

Code from MSDN:

```
Process.Start(path + "HelloWorld.exe", args, uname, password, domain);
```

Comment: +1 seems like a great think to know havent been able to make it work. I will keep trying maybe I am doing something wrong...

Comment: That method works great on my console application. On my windows service I get the exception: `System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Access is denied` I will continue trying

Comment: @TonoNam Any progress after 10 years?

Answer (score 2):

Austin's answer should work for the specific case. However, if you just want to know how to do this at installation time, then you want to use the [ServiceProcess.ServiceAccount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.serviceaccount.aspx) property. An example with more details [can be found here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14353/Creating-a-Basic-Windows-Service-in-C)

You might want to try the `LocalSystem` ServiceAccount type.