# How to create a C# service on many network PC's that all impersonate a single AD user account

Tags: c#, impersonation

I'm not really sure how to attack this and would appreciate any ideas.
I have about 20 custom c# applications distributed throughout our Windows network of about 100 domain joined PC's. One of the applications is an app that sets and gets permissions for all the individual functions of all the other applications and where the permission data is stored in an MSSQL DB.

Once the c# apps get past our permission app, I want the c# apps to be able to access network resources such as directories and SQL functions all as the same user so that I don't have to manage permissions on directories or tables and stored procedures for multiple users who come and go. That part is already done in the permission app and would be redundant.

I was thinking that I would be looking at a service that runs on the server that would impersonate the user and the c# client service would make requests to the server service. Without the server service, I would be looking at setting all the client services to impersonate the same user.

Am I even in the ballpark?

Comment: https://ehikioya.com/active-directory-user-impersonation/

Comment: Sounds like a possible answer would be to run those C# services as a service account user. Look at Active Directory Service Accounts. https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2009/09/10/managed-service-accounts-understanding-implementing-best-practices-and-troubleshooting/ Also look at running a C# service as a specific account https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17304400/make-windows-service-run-as-if-it-was-run-from-a-specific-user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this, you'll need to do two things:

1. Set up a [Service Account](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2009/09/10/managed-service-accounts-understanding-implementing-best-practices-and-troubleshooting/) (a special type of unattended account in Active Directory) with the right permissions.
2. Ensure your C# Services [are set up to run as this service account user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17304400/make-windows-service-run-as-if-it-was-run-from-a-specific-user).

Keep in mind, this is purely for unattended services. If you want a Windows Forms application to impersonate a service account, you're going to have to include the username/password either in the application itself (for instance, in a connection string), or you're going to have to include it in the executable shortcut link.

In either case, *it will be visible* to the end user (unless of course you encrypt it in the connection string case).  But a determined end-user will be able to decrypt it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In your scenario, are you suggesting that I set up a Managed Service Account as a service logon on a server and then let the 100 clients communicate to that with something like WCF?

Comment: If I understand your question, correctly, @guy, you want your applications to be able to communicate with the server (you have a client/server setup).  So you want the *clients* to impersonate a service account user (you may also want the server to impersonate that user; but that's not the focus of your question). Am I misunderstanding that?

Comment: I will rephrase my question: I have 20 apps that I want to be able to use network resources such as returning sql results or accessing directory permissions that the end user of those apps wouldn't ordinarily have access to. I am guessing that impersonation is the way to do this. I spit balled a client server type of solution so that I didn't have to do a special setup of each client, I don't have anything yet other than 20 apps doing their own thing so I can literally go in any direction. Would the MSA be a good solution to use on 100 clients? Is that a typical use for that?

Comment: You could create a special user for the application to use, and include its credentials in the source code; but you’d have to manage that user — eg make sure the credentials don’t expire, and it’d be a single point of access that is a bit of a security hole and allows an inside attacker to very easily get whatever permissions this application has. I’d personally go with the MSA, simply because it makes it more difficult to gain widespread access, but that does mean setting that account up on each machine, which is not optimal.

Comment: Thanks. I did some more reading based on the link you provided and I discovered that there are group MSA's that allow multiple PC's to share an MSA. I'm pretty sure this is what you meant in the first place but I somehow landed on an article describing a one PC limit per MSA. Thanks.